# Mapping Seq to JSON in Play 2

Tags: json, scala

I am working with play 2 with scala. I have Seq named customers like

```
customers: scala.Seq[(Option[Int], String, String)]
```

How can I convert it to a json object?
I am using this code

```
Json.obj(
     "status" -> true,
     "message" -> Json.toJson("Successful"),
     "customers" -> Json.toJson(customers.toString())
)
```

This give output like

```
{ 
    "status": true,
    "message": "Successful",
    "customers": "Vector((Some(1),ACTIVE,Md. Khairul Anam (Some(2),ACTIVE,Johirul Islam))"
}
```

I want to see output like

```
{ 
    "status": true,
    "message": "Successful",
    "customers": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Md. Khairul Anam "
            "status": "ACTIVE"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Johirul Islam"
            "status": "ACTIVE"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You should not use toString

Comment: `Json.toJson(customers)` ?

Comment: To add on the comments from @SarveshKumarSingh and @cchantep. You should not use the `toString` on your `customers` `Vector`. Unfortunately, `Json.toJson` only accepts instances of `Array`, so you should do something along the lines of `Json.toJson(customers.toArray)`. Note this only works if whatever is in the `Array` also has a `Writes`defined. I'm not sure whether tuples are supported though... So you might need to do something there...

Comment: I somehow feel that `tuples` should not be valid with respect to Json.